# White space in top/bottom of header on mobile (WordPress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Working on a WordPress website.

Everything looks fine on desktop but on mobile there is a significant amount of whitespace at the top and bottom of the header.

New to WordPress so I'm having a hard time figuring out what is going on.

Here's a link to the website: http://reluctant.ceo

I would like to note that when I change the size of my browser window this problem does not occur, only when I'm looking at it on my iPhone.

Also, when I turn of "responsive layout" in the theme options I still have this issue on my iPhone.

One more thing, not sure if it matters but the header is using Slider Revolution.

Comment: Cool Site! I don't think the issue is your header. The padding on that div stays the same regardless of screen size. I think the issue is the revolution slider resizing. It must be set to try and center within the div it is in instead of rest at the top.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, I think you are correct, however the only options I see within Revolution Slider for positioning are "center, left or right" [Screenshot of settings](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9uo2tbib0byzm44/Screenshot%202016-05-31%2019.54.19.png?dl=0)

Comment: It might need a custom style, though this is weird. I've used Rev slider a lot and it always positions at the top of the div its in. Might be a setting ive never checked before. I can help more once I have a chance to dig in.

Comment: Anything you can find would be a huge help, I'm going to continue trying to mess around with it as well. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey James, were you ever able to take a second look at this?

Comment: Hi @ryanbilak . I just looked at the problem again, sorry I didn't do it sooner. Your problem lies here: .vc_row .vc_row-o-content-middle. I see you are using visual composer, and the box the rev slider is in is set to align it's contents in the middle. So the rev slider is shrinking in height but it's container is staying the same and it is aligning in the middle of it. If you can figure out a way to make the row it is in not align middle and also not take up the height of the viewport you should be good. I can't help much there without access to the admin

Comment: Wow that was super easy to fix, I just deleted the VC row that had the slider and added the slider shortcode in the classic editor. Thanks for the help! I think I initially must have created a row and inserted the slider into it instead of just adding the slider.

Comment: Glad it worked out! Working with VC can be nice but it's super quirky, and a little overkill. Still it's a good tool for quick easy projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I had my revolution slider inside of a VC row element. I needed to delete the row and simply replace it with just the revolution slider instead of placing the slider inside a row.